# is there a way to share an event post to facebook or mailchimp?

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I understand there is a way to share an event post directly to our fb page or mailchimp content.
is that done through civicrm?

thank you.

Comment: Hi Theresa. Welcome to SE. Can you clarify your comment re Mailchimp. Surely that is a mail blast tool and hence if you are sending out a Mailing you would simply include a link to your Event Info or Event Registration pages. I don't think there is anything more you can do than that

Comment: You can embed drupal views directly in CiviMail templates so they pick up new content every time. I've never used the mailchimp plugin so I dont know how the mailings are composed, but maybe something similar. There's also lots of ways to auto publish drupal feeds to Facebook, so create a view of latest civi events with an rss feed and publish that

Answer (score 1):

In CiviCRM you can create events and manage (registered) participants at an event.
CiviCRM also provides an online registration form for events.

You can use the link to the public information page and the online registration form in a mail send from mailchimp or in a message on facebook. As far as I know there is no automatic way of doing this.

If you want more information also take a look at the user guide of CiviCRM: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/what-is-civievent/